# generate our own id document with firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I choose the id document that I want to use :

```
firebase.firestore().collection("Users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection("tasks").add({task:task.taskname,category:task.category})
```

Here, I create a randomly id document but I want to choose one (I mean the id of the document in the collection tasks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`someCollectionRef.add(/* data */)` is an alias for `someCollectionRef.doc().set(/* data */)`.

So to specify your own ID, just use:

```js
yourCollectionRef.doc(/* your id */).set(/* your data */);
```

```js
firebase.firestore()
  .collection("Users")
  .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
  .collection("tasks")
  .doc(/* your custom ID here */)
  .set({
    task: task.taskname,
    category: task.category
  })
  .then(() => console.log('success!'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('failed to set doc data!', err));
```

To place the document ID in the document, you can split this chain into two parts as below. Unless you plan on using [Collection Group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), you could use [`FieldPath.documentId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#static-documentid) to query documents by their ID instead without needing to store it in the document.

```js
const myTaskDocRef = firebase.firestore()
  .collection("Users")
  .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
  .collection("tasks")
  .doc(/* your custom ID here */);

myTaskDocRef
  .set({
    id: myTaskDocRef.id,
    task: task.taskname,
    category: task.category
  })
  .then(() => console.log('success!'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('failed to set doc data!', err));
```

Comment: Thank you! And if I want to use in this document, the id of the document, is it possible? For example, for the id document X, I use another filed "id" that is equal to X

Comment: @user123456 see updated answer

Answer (score -1):

Adding a document using .add() returns a document reference object

So using the following code from the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document), this is the code you want:

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
db.collection("cities").add({
    name: "Tokyo",
    country: "Japan"
})
.then((docRef) => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

docRef.id holds the id of the document you added.